# java.lang.IllegalStateException error

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-adapter, illegalstateexception

I'm calling an `ASyncTask` to update my adapter, and once in a while I'm getting this runtime error when it's populating my list

> E/AndroidRuntime(16197): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread.

Is it a bad idea to populate my adapter from a background thread, like the error message implies?

I'm calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` in `onPostExecute()`, but I also get the same error when I call it in `onProgressUpdate()`.

Here's my ASyncTask. Assume fetchOneItem() fetches a single item out of a list of items, fills out the name/description, and moves on to the next item in the next iteration.

```
private class GetItems extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, Integer> {
  @Override
  protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    pd = new ProgressDialog(context);
    pd.setTitle("Displaying...");
    pd.setMessage("Please wait.");
    pd.setCancelable(false);
    pd.setIndeterminate(true);
    pd.show();
    TextView myMsg = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.topMsg);
    myMsg.setText("Displaying items...");
  }

  protected Integer doInBackground(Integer... params) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    do {
      fetchOneItem(); // fetches 1 item
      myList.add(new Item(name, description));
      Log.i(TAG, "Adding " + name + ", " + desc + ", adapter size = " + myAdapter.getCount());
      publishProgress(i);
    } while (doneFetching != true);
    Log.i(TAG, "Completed loading, i =" + i);
    return i;
  }

  protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
    TextView myMsg = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.topMsg);
    myMsg.setText("Displaying " + Integer.toString(values[0].intValue()) + " items");
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(Integer numItems) {
    TextView myMsg = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.topMsg);
    myMsg.setText("Displayed " + numItems + " items");
    myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    allItemsLoaded = true;
    Log.i(TAG, "Adapter size = " + myAdapter.getCount());
    pd.dismiss();
  }
}
```

Comment: In stead of updating the `Adapter` directly on the background thread, send the (intermediate) results to the UI thread and add the results to the adapter on that. Either `onProgressUpdate()` or `onPostExecute()` will do, since both get called on the UI thread.

Comment: I've added my AsyncTask code to my original post. By updating the Adapter, do you mean moving my myList.add() from doInBackground() to either onProgressUpdate() or onPostExecute()? If so, how do I pass 2 variables (the integer and the Item) to either methods?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. To pass multiple values to the methods, just wrap them in a simple object, say `Tuple`. Alternatively, you can probably allocate a temporary list for the duration of the `AsyncTask`, add items to that from the background thread and then retrieve and add them to the adapter on the UI thread. That would be kind of similar to the producer-consumer pattern, but because none of the callbacks happen concurrently, it's a lot simpler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, as you can see android doesn't allow you to do this. If you want to update any view you should do it in the UI thread. But you should also never use slow operations in the UI thread such as network communcation which is isn't allowed in android. In fact you should keep the UI code as short as you can because if it takes too long then android will think your app has crashed.

**Edit:** I think you are using a ArrayAdapter which will notify changes when you update it.

So you got two choices:

Use your ArrayAdapter but update it in the UI thread.

Or implement your own subclass of BaseAdapter and you were doing it right.

ArrayAdapter is intended for simple situations, often with static data set.

Comment: This is kinda a catch-22 situation then isn't it? I wish to update the view, so I should do it in the UI thread, and it's a slow operation, so I should never do it in the UI thread. So exactly what should I do?

Comment: Well just looked into old code and apperently onPostExecute() should run in UI. If i understand you correctly you are doing it right. can you show a sample of your code?

Comment: I've added my AsyncTask code to the original post. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I have edited my answer, do you see it? You need to tell us which Adapter you extend?

Comment: I'm extended an ArrayAdapter. I've tried only adding to the list in OnProgressUpdate() instead of doInBackground() and so far so good. I probably need to test it more since the crashes don't happen very deterministically.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see you are trying to update the list view in "real time" right?

Well, I don't know how to do it, so I suggest you to implement a refresh button to call this AsyncTask. It's important to send a DialogProgress if you want to show to the user that you are actually updating the list view. Hope it helps!

Comment: I do have a progressdialog that informs the user that something is happening. The AsyncTask runs and fetches the list items automatically, and I don't wish for the user to have to intervene by tapping on a refresh button - it should be automatic.

Answer (score 0):

Posting late but might help someone facing similar situations.

Problem: You have a long running operation and want to take it to a background thread. Also after the operation is completed, you want to update views on UI thread.

Solution:

```
//spawn a new thread for background processing.
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //starting your background operation.
            //this is a network call.
            final Location location = BackendApi.builder().getSlaveLocation(mActivity.getApplicationContext(), "xyz", null);

            //now i want to update views on UI thread.
            new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //this code will run on UI thread.
                    myView.setText("Latitude: " + location.getLatitude());
                }
            });
        }
    }).start();
```

Before updating the views/adapters, make sure the activity is not destroyed.